# Installed Windows 10, file permissions causing all sorts of problems with cygwin

Tags: windows, permissions, git, cygwin, truecrypt

A little bit about my setup:

Was previously running Windows 7 with [0Patch](https://0patch.com/), finally installed Windows 10 (clean install).  All of my data is stored within an encrypted VHD (TrueCrypt/VeraCrypt) on a secondary drive.

I use cygwin to manage a bunch of custom shell scripts, git repos, etc.  I expected to be able to mount the VHD with my data and pick up where I left off, but there are all sorts of weird file permissions things going on.

Everything under the VHD is now owned by "Administrators" and not my primary user.  I had to restore my cygwin home directory from backup to get it working because bad permissions were causing issues with .bash_history, .ssh, and so on.

My Windows user is/was in the administrators group for both Windows 7 and Windows 10.

git repos are the biggest headache.  Even if I add every single repo to the global safe directories list, they have to reindex on every `git status`, and commits still fail.  The only thing that works is to edit the NTFS file permissions by:

- changing the owner to "me"
- replacing all child objects with inheritable permissions

But I'm very leery of the unforeseen consequences of changing permissions en masse like this.  What actually happened here and is this is a safe bulk operation to perform?

Comment: It’s entirely normal for everything to be owned by _Administrators_. Windows did not change this, it was already like that before. The default ACL makes sure you have all the expected permissions.

Comment: OK, so this is a cygwin-specific issue?